# TinyMCE spellchecker request error 404

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, tinymce

I have searched in many ways to get the solution of this problem but not found any working solution.

I have visited many questions on this platform but not found any working solution.

I know that i can use the browser checker but this is not the case. I have to use the editor's spellchecker.

**Problem**

When i click the spellcheck option under tools it did not work and shows this error

> Spellchecker request error : 404

I have the following code to initiate the plugin.

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    extended_valid_elements : "script[charset|defer|language|src|type|width|height]",
    relative_urls : false,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker,jbimages",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor jbimages", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'p', block: 'p'},
        {title: 'h1', block: 'h1'},
        {title: 'h2', block: 'h2'},
        {title: 'h3', block: 'h3'},
        {title: 'h4', block: 'h4'},
        {title: 'h5', block: 'h5'},
        {title: 'h6', block: 'h6'},
    ]
 }); 
</script>
```

Kindly let me know how to solve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error is refering to a "file not found" from your HTTP server.
I suggest that you double-check all paths refering to TinyMCE in your project.
Maybe TinyMCE require a script that you mooved or renamed his folder ?
Sometimes it happends to me: I change folder's structures so i need to go deep in "plugin's" sources to set the correct paths too.
Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I installed TinyMCE recently, and all the plugin files in my distro were named pluginname.min.js and TinyMCE was looking for pluginname.js.

Renaming the files for the plugins had everything working for me.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE's spellchecker plugin is an additional download. It is a server-side processing that requires a PHP package.

But you can tell TinyMCE to use your user's browser's native spellchecker by setting `browser_spellchecker` to `true`, instead of using the plugin.

For more info, see [TinyMCE Spell Checking](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/spell-checking/)